# Переносное значение слова "жёлтый"

Tags: лексика, значение-слов

Откуда пошла дурная слава о жёлтом цвете как символе фальша и ерунды?

Comment: Может быть от того, что золото имеет жёлтый цвет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы про [желтую прессу](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D1%91%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0) или про желтую журналистику, то, скорее всего, это название произошло от цвета газет, которые печатали на дешевой желтоватой бумаге.
А в других контекстах желтый цвет символизирует счастье и жизнерадостность.

Comment: Да, я именно про это имел в виду. Спасибо!